# catch(Exception e) followed by if (e instanceof Exception)

Tags: java, exception

Today i stumbled upon this piece of code

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   if (e instanceof Exception) {
      ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}
```

Does the if-else branching make any sense? Wouldn't caught `Exception e` always be an instance of `Exception`?

Comment: nope it doesn't make any sense. Maybe before it was "SomethingException" and they removed later on "Something".

Comment: It doesn't make sense, in this case `e` will always be an instance of `Exception`

Comment: I would definitely look through the history in source control to see what was there originally. I would expect something like `catch (Throwable e) {...}`

Comment: A decent optimizing compiler would probably throw that else part away. But we'll, javac isn't one of those compilers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes `e` would always be an instanceof `Exception`. As such the code you posted wouldn't make much sense.

Even if you'd want to handle different exceptions you'd rather do one of the following (example):

```
catch( IOException e) {
  //handle IOExceptions
}
catch( MyUserException e) {
  //handle user exceptions
}
... //any other exceptions you want to handle
```

If you want to handle some exceptions in the same way as of Java 7 you'd do something like this:

```
catch( IOException | MyUserException e) {
  //same handling for both
}
```

Prior to Java 7 you might encounter situations where you see `catch( Exception e)` and `instanceof` checks inside the catch-block but one should be careful with such constructs and if you have better options (i.e. Java 7+ multi-catch) you should consider those.

Finally note that a catch-all expression like `catch(Exception e)` *can* be useful but it can also be a source for errors, especially if the handling is poor. In most cases you want to handle expected exceptions in a specific way (e.g. IOExceptions) and let all others bubble up. Of course your code might want to catch all uncaught exceptions at some point (e.g. to log them) and that's where you'd use `catch(Exception e)` - but you should be aware of the implications and what to do in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The code above would not make any sense as e would always be an object(instance) of exception class.So to be more clear the program control will never enter else block as if(**e instanceof Exception**) will always e true.